# Dynamic Named Range - Disparate Cells

Tags: excel

Is it possible to produce a dynamic named range that chooses between multiple pre-existing named ranges using a formula?

Specifically I have two ranges as follows:

- I have a named range **PriceListVIC**
- I have a second range **PriceListQLD**

Based on the selection by a user in a third cell (VIC or QLD) I want the named range **PriceList** to point to appropriate range.

I realise I can do this in VBA. However some of the places these ranges are used are in Validation Lists - and I keep having issues changing the validation list in a cell (*something about **formula1** being read only*). A dynamic named range seems a reasonable alternative - but I can't seem to get my head around how to build one that works. I need something like

Range Name : PriceList

Refers To : =if(A1="VIC",PriceListVIC,if(A2="QLD",PriceListQLD,""))

But .. something like this that works, 'cause this doesn't ... is this possible?

Thanks Ken

Comment: well in that snippet you wrote, the cell has changed from A1 to A2 in the 2 IFs. So is that correct? Also qualify the Sheet, like: `=if(Sheet1!$A$1="VIC",PriceListVIC,if(Sheet1!$A$1="QLD",PriceListQLD,""))` . This is definitely possible to create a dynamic named range, instead of using the INDIRECT formula..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a named range called 'PriceList' and specify it as

=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$A$1)

Now, depending upon whether you write "PriceListVIC" or "PriceListQLD" in Sheet1!A1 the third range 'PriceList' will refer to one of the other named ranges.

This works in validation lists as well.

Comment: There's a thought. In fact I can modify the validation list to be =INDIRECT("TABLENAME"&dtActiveState).
- Thanks.